# Some character not work with fontsquirrel webfont

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts

I experienced a problem with the fontsquirrel webfont generator. Two special hungarian chars (ő, ű) do not exist in the output font files, while the input files **do**. On the other hand, I can not find any settings (like in Cufon), to set which chars should or should not be contained in tha pack. Some suggestions? The font is 'Aller', BTW.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you should be addressing this issue to fontsquirrel support - you will get faster feedback imo. http://www.fontsquirrel.com/forum/discussion/58/international-hungarian-french-fonts-with-accented-characters maybe this can give you some info update.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately there is no solution for that, right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have similar problems with fonts š, č, ž in Slovenian language.

I usually download the font (or Kit), go to @font-face Generator, upload the ttf (or other font file) file and choose Expert customisation. In Subsetting choose Custom Subsetting... Custom language support and find Hungarian language. Than see if the Subset Preview has your special characters in it. Read the agreement and download customized font.

This works for me.

Comment: Yes, this is the way to do it. You must use the EXPERT settings, as the OPTIMIZED setting will give you a MacRoman subset by default.

Comment: Sorry for this late acception, I have not visited this site for a while. Thanks, anyways.