# @font-face : Accented characters not displaying right - only in Safari

Tags: css, fonts, safari, font-face

I am using an official webfont through @font-face on a website. Accented characters such as "é" are displaying fine in Chrome/Firefox, but they render with a default font (e.g. Arial) in Safari. The font files do include all these characters.

Chrome :

[image: Chrome]

Safari :

[image: Safari]

Here is the @font-face declaration used :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'simplon_bp_mono_lightlight';
  src: url('fonts/SimplonMono-Light-WebS.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('fonts/SimplonMono-Light-WebS.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('fonts/SimplonMono-Light-WebS.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('fonts/SimplonMono-Light-WebS.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('fonts/SimplonMono-Light-WebS.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('fonts/SimplonMono-Light-WebS.webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

I tried this solution but it didn't work : [Symbols in @font-face font are not displayed in Safari 5, are displayed correctly in Safari 6 and other browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592516/symbols-in-font-face-font-are-not-displayed-in-safari-5-are-displayed-correctl)

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Is it a font that you bought? I found this article that might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997591/some-character-not-work-with-fontsquirrel-webfont

Comment: Have you checked if Safari uses a different font file than other browsers? You say the font contains those characters, but did you look in all the files?

Comment: Thank for your replies! Yes I did buy the font, it is provided with all web files (listed in my @font-face declaration). However, before using this web official version, I converted the TTF file via FontSquirrel. It resulted in the same problem (which is why I then bought the web version, hoping this would solve that). 
I confirm that Safari uses .woff file; I forced Chrome to use the same (instead of woff2), and it still displays correctly in Chrome, which proves that the files are OK. (Please note that the original font file does include the accentued characters, it works OK in Chrome)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

OK I figured it out. It seems that the accented characters where different from the regular ones. My client might have copy-pasted text from Word (I guess), because if I manually rewrite each character, it then works. This is really strange because if I look to source HTML, the characters really look the same. This is a stupid outcome but still, maybe it'll help someone in the future. If someone has an explanation for this difference between characters despite looking exactly the same (and displaying correctly in Chrome), I would be interested to learn about this.

Comment: Thanks for this. Exact same problem with a client pasting text from Word into WordPress. If anyone knows how to explain this phenomenon I'd be very interested.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'd be very interested to have an explanation of the issue as well!

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteMartin Just format your text in a text-only editor in order to remove strange characters.

Comment: @guylabbe.ca yes I was looking more for an explanation of why there are different characters for the exact same character ("é" for example), but indeed it works fine when using a text editor.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteMartin I am sorry, I must admit that I have no idea why we have this result. This must have something to do with the charset or invisible characters. I am sure someone out there might have a simple explanation for this.

Comment: Perhaps it is due to [unicode equivalence] (https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Canon_Compat_Equivalence) and [normalization forms] (https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms). Safari is probably decomposes (NFD) accented characters into two characters with the second one being combining diacritic mark. Try this in a javascript console: `'\u00e9' == 'e\u0301'.normalize()`

Comment: Amazing! Thank you.

Comment: I had the same problem, noticed that the text copied from a PDF was displaying `e + ́ ` instead of é

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add this tag to the head of your HTML:

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

You can read more about setting specific character sets at [this page](https://www.bluehost.com/help/article/character-sets-in-html).

Comment: It's not a charset-related problem.

Comment: @guylabbe.ca yes it is and this does solve it in some cases like mine at least.