# Wordpress sees copied text from word with diacritics as two characters [iphone typekit font problem]

Tags: iphone, wordpress, font-face, typekit

I use adobe typekit (//use.typekit.net/xxx.js) fonts on my Wordpress page. Encoding in HTML head is set to UTF-8, database tables and columns collations are both utf-8. Every device and browser are displaying fonts on page properly, instead of iphone mobile devices.

When it comes to iphone, it's not valid. Every polish character it displays in some other font face.

I found that the problem only occurs with copied texts from Word. Every character like Ś, Ź, Ć, Ó behaves as if they were two separate characters. For example **Ś** is S and `, Ź is Z and ` and so on. When text is copied to editor like Notepad++ I can select it in two different ways, as image below.

[image]

I am able to only select half of the letter. If I type Ś letter by keyboard, problem is solved. I can't do it this way because there are thousand of words and hundreds of texts.

Is there a way to force treat characters as one encoded character on iphone devices, not two different?

[I found out that someone had similar problem but there is no solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39773495/font-face-accented-characters-not-displaying-right-only-in-safari/39817617#39817617)